# yup.js Validate number field is larger than sibling, or nullable

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I'm using Yup.js to validate some form fields.

I have two integer fields, `Year Built` & `Year Renovated`.

`Year Built` is a required field, `Year Renovated` is not.

Year renovated can be left blank, however *if there is a value* it should be larger than year built (for a renovation certainly must occur after the date it was built).

I believe I need to use yup's `ref()` as well as yup's `when()` function. I've tried the following:

let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

```
yup.object().shape({
  yearBuilt     : yup.number().integer().min(1700).max(currentYear+1).required(),
  yearRenovated : yup.number().integer().when(
                    '$yearRenovated', (yearRenovated, schema)=>{
                        return yearRenovated > 0 ? 
                            schema.min(yup.ref('yearBuilt')).max(currentYear+1) :
                            schema.transform(emptyStringToNull).nullable()
                    }
                )
})
```

* The transform function, `emptyStringToNull` simply checks if `value === ''` and returns null if so.

The above does allow null values, as well as does correctly check for an integer. However it does not properly evaluate `yearRenovated > yearBuilt`. How do I properly check that if `yearRenovated` is not null, that it is greater than `yearBuilt`?

Thank you all so much for your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@JQuense, the owner of the repo had an eloquent solution, using `moreThan()`:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    yearBuilt: yup
      .number()
      .integer()
      .min(1700)
      .max(currentYear+1)
      .required(),
    yearRenovated: yup
      .number()
      .integer()
      .nullable()
      .moreThan(yup.ref("yearBuilt")) //<-- a whole lot neater than using a when conditional...
      .max(currentYear+1)
});
```

Hope that helps! Thank you @JQuense.

Comment: Really clean and easy way to check thanks @JQuense

Comment: I've to do a similar kinda thing. I have to compare two fields 'Min' and 'Max'.
The problem is if I put any value in `Min` and doesn't touch the `Max` field. Even in that case error message is showing. I want these comparisons only if both the input box have values.

Comment: @AnkitJaishwal - have you looked at using [Schema.when(...)](https://github.com/jquense/yup?tab=readme-ov-file#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema)? You can have a conditional on `when(myField.min(), myOtherFiled.max())` or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

```
const schema = Yup.object({
  // -- snip --
  billAmount: Yup.number().nullable(),
  approvedAmount: Yup.number()
    .typeError("you must specify a number")
    .notRequired()
    .when("billAmount", (billAmount: any, schema: any) => {
      return schema.test({
        test: (approvedAmount: any) => {
          if (!approvedAmount) return true;
          return approvedAmount < billAmount;
        },
        message: "Approved Amount not gether then billAmount",
      });
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever You want to expecify a value from corrent key, just use the yup.ref("key"), in this way you can use this to create better conditions in yup validation schema!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Yup (Less than or Equal To):  https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/538#issuecomment-495340254

If you end up needing a less than or equal to implementation (<=) consider this:

```
number().max(5) // is <= 5
```