# TypeScript & Yup Error: Argument of type 'Reference<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Reference<number>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, yup

When using [`yup`](https://github.com/jquense/yup) v0.32.8 with TypeScript, we are getting the TS error message

> Argument of type 'Reference' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Reference'.
> Type 'Reference' is not assignable to type 'Reference'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)

when we attempt to use the `Yup.ref()` function with `Yup.moreThan()`, such as in [this SO question that does not use TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682114/741099).

Why is this error being raised when using TypeScript, and how can we fix it? Thanks!

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    minPrice: Yup
        .number()
        .positive('Must be positive')
        .integer('Must be an integer')
        .required('Required'),
    maxPrice: Yup
        .number()
        .positive('Must be positive')
        .integer('Must be an integer')
        .moreThan(Yup.ref('minPrice'))     // <- ERROR HERE!
        .required('Required'),
})
```

---

**Update:**

Changing to

```
    maxPrice: Yup
        .number()
        .positive('Must be positive')
        .integer('Must be an integer')
        .moreThan(Yup.ref<number>('minPrice'))
        .required('Required'),
```

results in the error

> Argument of type 'Reference' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Reference'.
> Type 'Reference' is not assignable to type 'Reference'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.  TS2345

Comment: Seems like this issue has been fixed with this [Pull request](https://github.com/jquense/yup/pull/1208) but it's not released yet. May be you can directly install the package from [source](https://github.com/jquense/yup)

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a generic type to `Yup.ref`. It default to unknown and cause the error because `moreThan` expect a `Reference<number>`.

```js
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    minPrice: Yup
        .number()
        .positive('Must be positive')
        .integer('Must be an integer')
        .required('Required'),
    maxPrice: Yup
        .number()
        .positive('Must be positive')
        .integer('Must be an integer')
        .moreThan(Yup.ref<number>('minPrice'))
        .required('Required'),
})
```

---

Update: This require a new version of yup that is still unreleased. Until it get released, you can use:

```js
moreThan(Yup.ref<number>('minPrice') as Reference<number>)
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried your suggestion but a different error appeared. Updated the question to show the new error